# No custom fields on Post/Page edit pages

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress 3.1.2 and custom fields are not appearing on the Post and Page edit pages. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Screen Options in the top right menu and see if Custom Fields is unchecked or not.

Comment: Screen Options seems to be gone as well... There's only 'Help'

Comment: "Nevermind, found it" ????!!!! Hey, this is the community ! Won't you say what you did to fix it ? So you want help, but don't bother helping others ?